# Explanation about Garbage collection python

Tags: python, list, garbage-collection

Hi im not sure if this is related to garbage collection in python but im looking for some guidance in how it works under the hood.
Below is a part of my program.

```
def get_data():

 templist = []

 '''
 does stuff to fill templist with newest data
 '''

 return templist

def save_data(new_list, old_list):

 '''
 loops to check for updates.
 if update, write to file
 '''
 if not old_list:
    for n in new_list:
        write_file(n)
 else:
    for n, o in zip(new_list,old_list):
        if n[1] != o[1]:
            write_file(n)
 return new_list

comparelist = []

while True:

 newlist = get_data()
 comparelist = (save_data(newlist, comparelist))
```

I have checked with the id() function, and newlist gets passed as a new object each time to newlist, which then gets passed to comparelist (still memomery reference to templist.

My questions is this:

- each lap, is the lists that are no longer used destroyed?
- Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The real question is:  What are you worried about?  Python deletes things when it does a garbage collection, which can happen whenever it wants to.  Unless something is going wrong, you just shouldn't care.  I haven't had to care in 30 years.

Comment: @frankYellin You are right, i'm overthinking things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How and when objects are collected is generally a non issue, you should only care about how long you keep strong references to them around, which is mostly solved by scoping and knowing which objects you are keeping alive yourself.

When the object's reference count drops to zero, it's marked for deletion, when that deletion occurs is implementation dependent. In the reference CPython implementation, it runs immediately after it reaches 0 https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html#c.Py_DECREF

To save on a bit of time CPython will keep a few lists alive after they are deallocated, to be reused later to prevent creating completely new objects every time, so there's really nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you, i'm probably overthinking things :)